# How do I extract data from a many to many relationship in a specified format for use in a checkbox using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, join

ll
The table structure is as shown below.
[image: Table structure]

As an example, I want the enrollment details of a student, let's say the student with ID 3.

I expect the query result to be in the above format.
[image: Expected Output]

I intend to use the true / false or 0 , 1 column to be linked to a list of check-boxes at the front-end. This way a student can check / uncheck his own enrolled courses easily.

**More Info**

My project will be created in ASP.Net MVC. So, I am OK with LINQ queries as well. Assume standard model code with no annotations.

**EDIT:**
I didn't write my attempt as I simply didn't get far enough to post it here.
But here it is

```
SELECT COURSE.CNAME, 0
FROM COURSE
union
SELECT COURSE.CNAME, ENROLLMENT.EID
FROM COURSE INNER JOIN ENROLLMENT
ON COURSE.CID = ENROLLMENT.CID
INNER JOIN STUDENTS
ON STUDENTS.SID = ENROLLMENT.SID
WHERE STUDENTS.SID = 3
```

Comment: "I expect the query result to be in the above format." -- The database job is to store and retrieve data fast and efficiently. It's not the database job to format data.

Comment: @TheImpaler SO do you suggest just retrieving the data and processing it in the Business Logic end?

Comment: @VRM Usually you perform all formatting in the presentation layer. The business logic layer is a mid-tier one. It handles high level abstractions and decisions, not presentation (front end), not persistence (back end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `left join`. This would give you the result you want for student `3`:

```
select
    e.eid,
    c.cname,
    c.cid,
    case when e.eid is null then 0 else 1 end as isenrolled
from course c
left join enrollment e on e.cid = c.cid and e.sid = 3
order by is_enrolled desc, e.eid, c.cid
```